# the unknown steps to convert a hex string to a int

Tags: c++, encryption, hex, int

i have a unsigned character string (here in hex: d3 ea 12 f7 f7 ). Now this string, somehow converts into the integer 37224 and i want to know the steps of conversion u have to take

all i know that since its an int, there is probably one char too much in the string since an int is 4 byte long and this string is 5 byte, its very possible that the first byte or the last byte needs to be discarded

it might be encrypted or the bytes are shifted or something like that?

any idea on how u could find out the steps of conversion?

unsigned char string in hex: d3 ea 12 f7 f7

int it converts to         : 37224

Comment: This question doesn't mathematically make sense.  Assume there's some function f(x) such that f(37224) = d3 ea 12 f7 f7.  You can find some `g` such that g(d3ea12f7f7) = 37224, but you have no guarantee that this g = inverse of f.  Though if there's some obvious pattern (that I'm too lazy to look for), then you might be able to assume that you've found the inverse.

Comment: Easy: f(x) = 37224 … For real answers you have to give us much more sample data.

Comment: Perhaps if we knew more about where this string come from and go into we could tell more. *Context* matter here. Are there any reason to expect encryption? In that case you are in a fix. On the other hand, if this is network traffic one could consider bit ordering and crc sections and paddings and what not.

Answer (score 3):

I shall elaborate a bit on my comment:

> any idea on how u could find out the steps of conversion?

You can't.  Well, you can guess, or you can assign one arbitrarily, but knowing the conversion with certainty is not possible.  A single output and a single input are meaningless.  You might as well just assume the function is:

```
if (in == 37224) { return "d3 ea 12 f7 f7"; }
```

There are infinitely many functions such that these two values map to each other.  Looking for the 'correct' function is not possible.  As I said in the comment, you can guess the function, and if you can find some kind of meaningful pattern, you can probably assume that it's correct.  Even if you see an obvious pattern though, with a sample size of one, that could be a dangerous function.

Think of it this way:

```
f(2) = 4
```

What is the inverse of the function `f`?  You could guess `f^-1(x) = x/2`.  But, it could also be `f^-1(x) = log2(x)` (basically either `f(x) = 2x` or `f(x) = 2^x`).

The same idea applies here.  You can assume that you found the correct inverse function, but you can never know for sure.

`g(y)` is the inverse of `f(x)` if and only if for all x in the domain of f, g(f(x)) = x.

Knowing that for one value of x that g(f(x)) = x does not prove that `g(y)` is the inverse of `f(x)`.  (It's basically meaningless knowledge actually [other than it's an intersection of `g` and `f`] unless you're willing to take a leap of faith that it is indeed the inverse.)